# Is there a way to stop a program after it outputs n lines?

Tags: linux, pipe

Ive tried the following, but it still waits for the program to finish executing
lnx>someprogram | sed -n '1,10p'

Maybe a pipe may not be the correct way to go about this. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Regards,
Puji

Comment: Is `lnx > someprogram` meant (as written) that you're executing `lnx` and redirecting output into a file named `someprogram` and then truncating the resultant output of THAT operation to 10 lines? If so, there's your problem: you're redirecting the **entire** output into the file **first** and **then** limiting the number of lines.

Comment: lnx> is just part of my host. So actual command is simply "someprogram | sed -n '1,10p'". My issue is that someprogram keeps running however even after sed outputs 10 lines.